# Default featured image set as background image

Tags: loop, post-thumbnails

I'm using the following code to set my post featured image as a `background-image`…

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):

 $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 

endif; ?>
```

How can I add an else statement so if the post doesn't have a featured image it will use a specific image `/images/featured.jpg` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use else below your code.

```
<?php 
if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
else:
    $image = array( '/images/featured.jpg' ); 
endif;

$image_url = $image[0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
endif; ?>

<div style="background:url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>)">
<p>teing for background image</p>
<p>teing for background image</p>
<p>teing for background image</p>
<p>teing for background image</p>
<p>teing for background image</p>
</div>
```

[image]